# How to empty a taxonomy?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have been messing around with data migration and I ended up with a rather corrupted taxonomy with the wrong terms in it.

I would like to completely delete the terms inside the taxonomy. I have not found any drush command for doing it. A module search was also unsuccessful, in fact I found a dead one named [cleantaxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/cleantaxonomy).

I can try to build a SQL query to do this but I am sure someone stepped into this before.

Comment: Side note, don't do this with raw SQL.  You will more than likely end up with an inconsistent database if you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) makes that pretty easy:

> This module provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.

Or you could do it manually:

```
foreach (taxonomy_vocabulary_load_multiple(FALSE) as $vocab) {
  taxonomy_vocabulary_delete($vocab->vid);
}
```

If you have a lot of vocabs/terms it would be better to split that up into a batch job to avoid out of memory errors.

Comment: should the batch technique be used in `hook_uninstall` as well (when programmatically uninstalling a vocabulary)?

Comment: To be safe I'd say yes that's a good idea, but I don't know of a way to get a Drupal batch into `hook_uninstall()`. You can do it in `hook_update_n()` as you're provided a batch environment to work with, but I've never tried it on uninstall (plus running an update on an uninstalled module obviously doesn't make sense). I just updated the answer, Drupal has an internal function to make that a bit more efficient. I still think it should go in a batch job for large vocabs though

Comment: I noticed you just edited the code and migrated into using `taxonomy_vocabulary_delete`. Without limiting it to a specific vid, wouldn't that general loop delete all vocabularies? `$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocab machine name') -> vid` (with appropriate null testing of course)

Comment: Yes, by 'empty taxonomy' I thought you meant the whole lot :) If you only want to empty a single vocab then yeah, load up the voacb object with whichever method you like, then pass that `$vid` to `taxonomy_vocabulary_delete()`

Comment: Oh, I should leave it up to the original poster :) I'm just observing this issue and chiming in, as I'm currently trying to programmatically manage a vocabulary in my module.